# Python: How to plot numbers on Y-Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, plotly-python, footprint

**This is a financial chart.**
I wish to plot numbers on canvas(figure) chart graph having x axis as timeseries and y axis as price, example image I have designed on photo editor to make my point also sharing data which will go through for plotting.

Can anyone please help me how can I achieve this result. This below raw data is resampled in 15 minute also group by price (LTP - Last traded price).

[Sharing raw data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9asz19eeqkl3i9w/security_chart_WIPRO-EQ.csv)
[Example chart to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmPL1.jpg)

Comment: Please try to put all your data inside your question rather than a link, Do you want to represent this data in a bar graph.

Comment: as per other comment - data as text

Comment: Will you accept this answer? Does help when you post further questions as people understand if you will contribute.

Answer (score 1):

- what you describe is a `Scatter(mode="text")` this is second trace in code below
- your mocked up picture also shows lines around text on the canvas.  This is done by a **bar** trace
- the majority of the code is simulating your data as you have not provided

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# generate some sample data
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
            [
                np.arange(326.75, 324.95, -0.05),
                pd.date_range("24-sep-2021 09:00", freq="15min", periods=6),
            ],
            names=["LTP", "Time"],
        )
    )
    .reset_index()
    .pipe(
        lambda d: d.assign(
            BuyVolume=np.random.choice(
                np.concatenate([[0], np.random.randint(0, 1000, (len(d)))]),
                len(d),
                p=[0.9] + [0.1 / len(d) for _ in range(len(d))],
            ),
            SellVolume=np.random.choice(
                np.concatenate([[0], np.random.randint(0, 1000, (len(d)))]),
                len(d),
                p=[0.9] + [0.1 / len(d) for _ in range(len(d))],
            ),
        )
    )
)

print(df.head(20).to_markdown())

# create text to appear on chart
df = df.assign(
    plotText=lambda d: d["BuyVolume"].astype(str) + "x" + d["SellVolume"].astype(str)
)
# only rows that have either a buy or sell volume
dfp = df.loc[df["plotText"].ne("0x0")]
# ranges for bars around the text
dfx = dfp.groupby("Time").agg(min=("LTP", "min"), max=("LTP", "max"))
fig = go.Figure(
    [
        go.Bar(
            x=dfx.index,
            y=dfx["max"] - dfx["min"],
            base=dfx["min"],
            marker={"color":"white", "line":{"color":"black", "width":3}}
        ),
        go.Scatter(x=dfp["Time"], y=dfp["LTP"], text=dfp["plotText"], mode="text"),
    ],
)
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, template="plotly_white")
```

#### sample data

|  | LTP | Time | BuyVolume | SellVolume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 326.75 | 2021-09-24 09:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 326.75 | 2021-09-24 09:15:00 | 0 | 983 |
| 2 | 326.75 | 2021-09-24 09:30:00 | 0 | 74 |
| 3 | 326.75 | 2021-09-24 09:45:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 326.75 | 2021-09-24 10:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 326.75 | 2021-09-24 10:15:00 | 705 | 0 |
| 6 | 326.7 | 2021-09-24 09:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 326.7 | 2021-09-24 09:15:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 326.7 | 2021-09-24 09:30:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 326.7 | 2021-09-24 09:45:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 326.7 | 2021-09-24 10:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | 326.7 | 2021-09-24 10:15:00 | 0 | 593 |
| 12 | 326.65 | 2021-09-24 09:00:00 | 0 | 630 |
| 13 | 326.65 | 2021-09-24 09:15:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 14 | 326.65 | 2021-09-24 09:30:00 | 0 | 968 |
| 15 | 326.65 | 2021-09-24 09:45:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 16 | 326.65 | 2021-09-24 10:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 17 | 326.65 | 2021-09-24 10:15:00 | 213 | 0 |
| 18 | 326.6 | 2021-09-24 09:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 19 | 326.6 | 2021-09-24 09:15:00 | 0 | 0 |

#### plot

[image]

#### stacked bar and hover

- there is too much text to plot on a graph
- encode data into a stacked bar chart
- use `rangeslider`, `rangeselector` to navigate **xaxis**
- first bar is required so there is clarity for `rangeslider`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from pathlib import Path
import itertools

df = pd.read_csv(
    Path.home().joinpath("Downloads").joinpath("security_chart_WIPRO-EQ.csv")
)
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"])
# df = df.sort_values("Time").head(200)

fig = px.bar(
    df.groupby("Time", as_index=False).agg(
        base=("LTP", "min"), y=("LTP", lambda s: s.max() - s.min())
    ),
    x="Time",
    y="y",
    base="base",
).update_traces(
    hoverinfo="none",
    hovertemplate="",
    marker={"color": "white", "line": {"color": "black", "width": 1}},
)
fig.add_traces(
    px.bar(
        df.sort_values(["Time", "LTP"])
        .groupby("Time")
        .apply(
            lambda d: d.assign(
                y=(d["LTP"] - d["LTP"].shift()), color=np.linspace(0, 1, len(d))
            )
        ),
        x="Time",
        y="y",
        base="LTP",
        hover_name="volume",
        color="color",
        hover_data={"color": False, "y": False},
    ).data
)
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis={
        "rangeselector": {
            "buttons": [
                dict(count=n, label=f"{n}hrs", step="hour", stepmode="backward")
                for n in [2, 4, 6, 8]
            ]
        },
        "rangeslider": {"visible": True},
        "range": [
            df["Time"].min() - pd.Timedelta(minutes=15),
            df["Time"].min() + pd.Timedelta(hours=4),
        ],
        "rangebreaks": [
            dict(bounds=[16, 9], pattern="hour"),
            dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]),
        ],
    },
    coloraxis={"showscale": False},
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
    height=800,
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I achieved the result, thank you for your help, I wanted to extend this query. As you can see the text is very close to each other that its hard to understand, I wish this space was sufficient enough that it becomes readable, I tried zooming and panning but the results are not satisfactory. Can you tell how to fix this, so that readability can be increased. Kindly click this dropbox link to refer an image producing the result. [example output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/meenqqoz78sej4d/chart.png)

Comment: can you provide the data rather than the image?   I have some ideas, but better to work with actual data rather than simulated data

Comment: Sure, attaching the link of data [Raw Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9asz19eeqkl3i9w/security_chart_WIPRO-EQ.csv)

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is footprint chart, if you google it and browse through image section of google, you will see many examples images. I have used candlestick sub-plots with scatter text plot. In my case plot is not visually clear.

Comment: Any updates Rob, waiting for your response. Are you able to solve this issue?

Comment: this took my interest,  out of best practice I normally don't work on closed questions. Really there is far too much data to encode in representation you want, hence need to rely on hoverinfo